# Chained async calls returning undefined response

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I seem to be getting undefined from my async code, and none of the answers I have found seem to work.

So my setup is router calls a controller, which calls a service, which calls a database.  The controller is like so (removed some validation etc to reduce code)

```
const { userService } = require('../services/index.services');

const postUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = {
      user_id: req.body.userId,
      user_status: req.body.userStatus,
      created_at: new Date(),
      updated_at: new Date(),
    };

    const result = await userService.createUser(user);
    console.log(result);

  } catch (err) {
    return apiResponse.ErrorResponse(res, err);
  }
};

module.exports = {
  postUser,
};
```

You can see I have a console log of the result.  Then my service class is like so

```
const { addUserToDb } = require('../database/users.db');

const createUser = async (user) => {
  try {
    const createdUser = await addUserToDb(user);
    console.log(createdUser);
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};

module.exports = {
  createUser,
};
```

That one also has a console log.  Then finally `users.db`

```
const pool = require('./database');

const addUserToDb = (user) => {
  pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }

    connection.query('INSERT INTO `users` SET ?', user, (err) => {
      if (err) { throw new Error(err); }
      pool.releaseConnection(connection);
      return user;
    });
  });
};

module.exports = {
  addUserToDb,
};
```

So you can see this adds the user to the database and returns the user.  So my user is successfully being inserted into the database.

My question is why am I getting undefined in both my console logs?  I am returning from all modules which is where I noticed a lot of other people had issues because of no returns.

So can someone explain why these may be undefined?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in your service class you have,

```
const createdUser = await addUserToDb(user);
```

But `addUserToDb` in `users.db` doesn't return a promise.
`addUserToDb` is a regular function that executes the query using callbacks.
Hence, even though you have `return user;` nested within the 2nd callback, it never returns the user value back to `createUser` in the service class as callbacks are asynchronous.
In fact, `addUserToDb` function in `users.db` doesn't wait for the callback to complete and thus returns undefined back to the service class.

And hence you see `undefined` being logged in your service class.

async/await only works with promises, not callbacks.

You need to refactor `./database` module to use promises instead of callbacks for `pool.getConnection` and `connection.query`.
I use `mysql2` npm module as it has a promise wrapper,
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper

And the reason why  `console.log(result);` in your controller is `undefined` is because you don't return anything from your service class.
You need to add `return createdUser;` in your service class's `createUser` method.